# Returning DataTable as response is giving column names in some unknown format

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am returning a column name with an underscore in it and some unknown format(maybe to me) is being returned.Other column names without '_' are being returned in lower case. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public System.Data.DataTable GetDummyTable()
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("COLUMN_ONE");
        dt.Columns.Add("COLUMN_TWO");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            System.Data.DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["COLUMN_ONE"] = i;
            row["COLUMN_TWO"] = "X" + i;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

.net core follow the camelcase convention when returning data.
I'm guessing the resolver sees x_xxx as a special case - I'm not sure.